# Sqlite3 db for geddy js

Tags: sqlite, geddy

It's my first time using Geddy JS and I'm starting to like it but when I tried using sqlite for development db I keep getting **Model adapter not found for Page. Set .adapter for this model, or set model.defaultAdapter** when I run geddy jake db:init / migrate.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sqlite3 support is very new. In fact, I don't think it's even on NPM yet because @mde was just working on it today.

For updates on this feature you can hop on the #geddy freenode IRC channel, or join our mailing list.

We also have a filesystem adapter that might already be on NPM. If it isn't, it should be soon.

Comment: Thanks, I just saw it in the git documentation so I thought it's already up and working.